# Delphi WinSock

Tags: delphi

Шлю данные из одной програмки в другую(локал хост), так вот, сервер получает отправленное сообщение на ура, клиенты - не получают ничего, сервер на TServerSocket, клиенты на WinSock. код клиента ниже, код отправки сервера тоже ниже.

```
//Сервер, отправка.
for i:=0 to ServerSocket1.Socket.ActiveConnections-1 do
  Begin
    ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[i].SendText('Проверка клиент номер ХХХ');
    RichEdit1.Lines.Add('Send To Client '+IntToStr(i))
  End;

//Клиент
wsastartup($101,vwsadata);
vsocket := socket(af_inet,sock_stream,ipproto_ip);
if vsocket = invalid_socket then halt(1);
fillchar(vsockaddr,sizeof(tsockaddr),0);
vsockaddr.sin_family := af_inet;
vsockaddr.sin_port := htons(cport);
vsockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr := inet_addr('127.0.0.1');

while  connect(vsocket,vsockaddr,sizeof(tsockaddr)) = socket_error do Sleep(1000);

getsockopt(vsocket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVBUF,PChar(@BufSize),vSize);
str:=Name;
send(vsocket,str[1],length(str)+1,0);

repeat
  FillChar(aBuf,BufSize,0);
  vSize := recv(vsocket,aBuf[0],BufSize,0);
  if vSize>0 then
  Begin
    SetLength(str,vSize);
    lstrcpyn(@str[1],@aBuf[0],vSize);
    Msg:=tMessage.Create;
    Msg.Text:=str;
    Msg.Timer:=GetTickCount+3000;
    MessageList.Add(Msg); //<<<<Никогда не происходит, в чем может быть ошибка?
  end else
  sleep(100);
until vsocket = SOCKET_ERROR;

closesocket(vsocket);
wsacleanup;
```

Дебаг клиента невозможен из за специфики(внедряемая DLL); По дебагу сервера, сообщение успешно отправлено.

Comment: если `vSize` будет ноль или отрицательно, то будет наблюдаемое поведение.

Отладить такое можно, причем достаточно легко. Для начала качаем [debug view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx). А в код добавляем вызовы [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx). Теперь можно смело запускать и смотреть лог в realtime. ну может чуточку нужно будет вывод отфильтровать.

Comment: vSize - полученое от сервера кол-во символов) если оно 0 или меньше, соответственно ничего выводить не нужно, ну с отладкой - да, погорячился, но всеже, в коде по идее ошибка(?), или я неверно понимаю работу на winsock с неблокирующем сокетом(TServerSocket - в неблокирующем режиме)?

Comment: суть vSize  я понимаю. В коде я вижу только странности.
`wsastartup($101,vwsadata);`. Принято вообще то $202 писать, хотя по факту эта строка ничего не решает.
`send(vsocket,str[1],length(str)+1,0);` - также странная - send может отправить не все, а часть. Более того, а как сервер узнает, сколько принимать? до первого нулевого символа?

да и сама процедура считывания у меня вызывает только шок.

Comment: Процедура считывания взята из статьи(собсно она то нормальная и нужна, впервые работаю с WinSock), статья из DRKB.
пы.сы по поводу send - в курсе, это просто для проверки сделано)

Comment: странная статья. Может для начала попробуете сделать  отдельное приложение, отладить там код, а потом уже браться за dll?

а код чтения ... читайте правильные [статьи](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). Я раньше постил даже ссылки на русский перевод.

Comment: За статейку спасиб конечн, почитаю. а по поводу отладить в программе - тоже идея, попробую)